# using pointer arithmetic to iterate, possible memory leak?

Tags: c, loops, memory-leaks, free, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm currently using the following code to get an "lowered" string:

```
void strlower(char** string)
{
    char* ptr = malloc((strlen(*string)+1) * sizeof **string);
    memcpy(ptr, *string, (strlen(*string)+1) * sizeof **string);

    while (*ptr) {
        if (*(ptr) >= 'A' && *(ptr) <= 'Z') {
            memset(*string + (strlen(*string) - strlen(ptr)), (char)(*(ptr)+32), sizeof **string);
        }
        ++ptr;
    }
    memcpy(*string, ptr, (strlen(*string) +1) * sizeof **string);  

    /// free(ptr); THROWS ERROR
    free(ptr);
    ptr = NULL;
}
```

If I try to `free(ptr);` I allocated with `malloc` it'll throw me an exception.

Is there an memory leak going on? can't I free it because it's empty? has it something todo with `null pointer`s? Is it undefined behaviour? would like to know!

Comment: `sizeof **string`... please don;t write code like that, confusing at best.

Comment: What's the problem with `tolower()` and a simple loop?

Comment: " it'll throw me an exception." - C does not support exceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `++ptr;`, you have *lost* the pointer returned by `malloc()`. Unless you pass the exact pointer returned by the memory allocator functions to `free()`, you'll invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

*Solution:* You need to keep a copy of the actual returned pointer somewhere to be passed to `free()` later.